# What is the best way to deliver real-time messages to Client that can not be requested

Tags: websocket, rabbitmq

We need to deliver real-time messages to our clients, but their servers are behind a proxy, and we cannot initialize a connection; webhook variant won't work.

What is the best way to deliver real-time messages considering that:

- client that is behind a proxy
- client can be off for a long period of time, and all messages must be delivered
- the protocol/way must be common enough, so that even a PHP developer could easily use it

I have in mind three variants:

1. WebSocket - client opens a websocket connection, and we send messages that were stored in DB, and messages comming in real time at the same time.
2. RabbitMQ - all messages are stored in a durable, persistent queue. *What if partner will not read from a queue for some time?*
3. HTTP GET - partner will pull messages by blocks. *In this approach it is hard to pick optimal pull interval.*

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Who is the SMS Gateway?

Comment: I meant I am developing a SMS gateway.

Answer (score 0):

Since you seem to have to store messages when your peer is not connected, the question applies to any other solution equally: *what if the peer is not connected and messages are queueing up?*

RabbitMQ is great if you want loose coupling: separating the producer and the consumer sides. The broker will store messages for you if no consumer is connected. This can indeed fill up memory and/or disk space on the broker after some time - in this case RabbitMQ will shut down.

In general, RabbitMQ is a great tool for messaging-based architectures like the one you describe:

- Load balancing: you can use multiple publishers and/or consumers, thus sharing load.
- Flexibility: you can configure multiple exchanges/queues/bindings if your business logic needs it. You can easily change routing on the broker without reconfiguring multiple publisher/consumer applications.
- Flow control: RabbitMQ also gives you some built-in methods for flow control - if a consumer is too slow to keep up with publishers, RabbitMQ will slow down publishers.
- You can refactor the architecture later easily. You can set up multiple brokers and link them via shovel/federation. This is very useful if you need your app to work via multiple data centers.
- You can easily spot if one side is slower than the other, since queues will start growing if your consumers can't read fast enough from a queue.
- High availability and fault tolerance. RabbitMQ is very good at these (thanks to Erlang).

So I'd recommend it over the other two (which might be good for a small-scale app, but you might grow it out quickly is requirements change and you need to scale up things).

Edit: something I missed - if it's not vital to deliver all messages, you can configure queues with a TTL (message will be discarded after a timeout) or with a limit (this limits the number of messages in the queue, if reached new messages will be discarded).

Comment: ``This can indeed fill up memory and/or disk space`` is it possible to configure RabbitMQ so that after queue size gets close to ``N`` messages will be saved on disk? And will this degrade performance of rabbitMQ on other queue processing?

Comment: As far as I know, no. You can set up a queue as persistent (messages will be kept across restarts) or not (messages will be lost after a RabbitMQ restart).

Comment: If storing messages in queue is a bad idea, then maybe using WebSockets would be more convinient for our clients? Because AMQP is kind of more advanced.

Comment: It's not a bad idea - you just have to make sure you monitor your queues and you have enough disk space. In the worst case an alarm should be triggered and publishers should be stopped. RabbitMQ does a lot more than WebSockets - but which one is a better fit depends what you need exactl.y